# Is Socket Id Reissued once a client disconnects and connects again server is on Socket.io and node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I want to implement one to one chat, I am confused on how to implement this.
I am trying to achieve this by sending a message to each socket but if a client gets disconnected and the Socket Id changes it won't be able to send the message on the socket id which was stored in the database. Any tips on how to implement this?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each fresh session ,new  client socket instance is created hence the id may change, so to be able to identify users ,you should rely on some user_id rather then the socket id, For example at the time of new session
u could implement some login logic like

```
io.on("connection", function(socket) {

   // Accept a login event with user's data
   socket.on("login", function(userid) {
       // store socket instance against userid in session store like redis.
    }); 
});
```

This way u are saving a fresh socket instance on every connection.

Note: Using sockets you can only send the message if the receiver is online if u want offline message functionality u may want to check other messaging brokers like rabbitmq

[Building NodeJs Chat Application with RabbitMQ](https://craigmckenna.com/build-a-simple-chat-application-with-rabbitmq-on-node-js.html)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. For offline functionality, i can store the messages in the database, right? So that when the user comes online he can retrieve those messages.

Comment: Yes you would have to build the  message queue in your own and every time the user is back make sure to retrieve all those message from the queue. Otherwise do considering RabbitMq or other message brokers like amqp they would handle the queue on their own.

Comment: I am new to socket.Io, was just playing around, maybe I can try making the same. Anyways Thanks for your help. :)